# Postgresql jsonb set-union of lists

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I am hoping it is straightforward to do the following:
Given rows containing jsonb of the form

```
{
  'a':"hello",
  'b':['jim','bob','kate']
}
```

I would like to be able to get all the 'b' fields from a table (as in select jsondata->'b' from mytable) and then form a list consisting of all strings which occur in at least one 'b' field. (Basically a set-union.)

How can I do this? Or am I better off using a python script to extract the 'b' entries, do the set-union there, and then store it back into the database somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the union set of elements in list 'b' of the json.

```
SELECT array_agg(a order by a) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT unnest(txt_arr) AS a FROM
     (SELECT  ARRAY(SELECT trim(elem::text, '"')
                    FROM   jsonb_array_elements(jsondata->'b') elem) AS txt_arr
      FROM   jtest1)y)z;
```

Query Explanation:

- Gets the list from b as `jsondata->'b'`
- Expands a JSON array to a set of JSON values from `jsonb_array_elements()` function.
- Trims the `"` part in the elements from `trim()` function.
- Converts to an array again using `array()` function after trimming.
- Get the distinct value by unnesting it using `unnest()` function.
- Finally `array_agg()` is used to form the expected result.